# asp.net mvc open the view in the read-only/disabled mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I have a asp.net mvc page which uses bootstrap and I need the page to open in the read only form
and not to be able to edit  the complete page.

One of doing it I know is using the jquery prop function and setting each field one by one
to disabled.

doing this for all controls ?

```
 $("").prop("disabled", false);
```

Is there any easy way to this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set disabled attribute of fieldset
Try all the controls between `<fieldset></fieldset>` element

```
<fieldset class="form-class">
</fieldset>
```

jQuery: `$('.form-class').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use this one code in js which will disable all controls , I think it's the easiest way to achieve .

```
$(":input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Here is the page which contains many different controls:

[image]